# how to get the value passed in value attribute of <input> html Tag in controller

Tags: visualforce, html

I am using an input tag in my visualforce page with type="Radio" and value="{!Selected}".

In the controller, I have declared the boolean "Selected" with get;set;. But when i select the radio button, the variable "selected" does not get updaated to true in controller.

I could not use selectoptions due to my requirement.

Should a different approach be followed to achieve the same

Comment: Is it possible to set a value to a controller variable through javascript? I mean in this case, can we set selected variable to true in the on click event in the input tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiply ways to achieve it:

- Use `apex:selectRadio` tag instead of html-input. You will then get the value of the variable into controller automatically. The Visualforce will do this job for you.
- You can still use html-input but then you should implement a structure that will take this value to controller. For example `apex:actionFunction`together with `apex:param`.

Example:

```
<apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!Selected}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="Option 1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="Option 2"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use selectoption as i need to disable/enable the radio buttons based on conditions.

Comment: @SFDCLearner Is it a reason why you can not use `apex:selectOption`??? What is with javascript and/or `itemDisabled` parameter?

Comment: Thanks. I tried using apex:selectoption. I tried to disable them via jquery but it did not work for select option radio buttons alone. Though it worked for other fields. i will try disabling through boolean in itemdisabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As mast0r mentioned, you can use apex:ActionFunction and Javascript to achieve this.

This example should help: http://www.salesforceworld.blogspot.com/2011/06/parameter-passing-using.html#!http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com/2011/06/parameter-passing-using.html

You create an ActionFunction wrapped around your radio button (let's call it `<apex:actionFunction name="someActionFunctionName"`). Create a Javascript function that takes in one parameter (let's say for example, myRadioElement) and calls the `name` parameter of the actionFunction, then passes in the value of your HTML element as the parameter, e.g. `someActionFunctionName(document.getElementByID(myRadioElement))`. You can then call the Javascript function on whatever event you want on the element, and the value can be received and accessed in your controller like:

```
boolean interviewdate=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myRadioElement');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <apex:selectRadio value="{!selected}">
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="true" itemLabel="First"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="false" itemLabel="Second"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="true" itemLabel="Third"/>
        **<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!testSelected}"  rerender="out" />**
     </apex:selectRadio>


    <apex:outputPanel id="out"> 
         <p>You have selected:</p> 
         <apex:outputText value="{!selected}"/> 
   </apex:outputPanel>
```